# Problema de instalacion Mysql-Server Mysql-Cliente Linux

Tags: mysql, debian

Estoy hace al menos una semana con este problema, llegue hasta a reinstalar el sistema operativo y que Mysql-server / Mysql-client sean las primeras cosas en instalarse para ver si no era un conflicto con otra cosa.

Segui muchos tutoriales, vi muchas explicaciones pero ninguna me resuelve este error.

[image: Error en consola]

Estoy ejecutandolo en root.

Tengo la ultima version de Parrot

Comment: Tienes un  problema con las dependencias, has un sudo apt-get update para que se actualice el repositorio e intenta instalar de nuevo.

Comment: apt-get update (Me indico que habia paquetes desactualizados), luego corri apt-get upgrade (Hizo actualizaciones correspondiente) apt-get update ahora mismo me dice que ya no hay nada para actualizar. Sigue con el mismo inconveniente

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes problemas con algunas dependencias.

Para corregirlo debes ejecutar

sudo apt-get autoclean para borrar todos los paquetes en memoria cache, luego.

sudo apt-get update para actualizar los repositorios.

Y por último instalar el paquete con

sudo apt-get -f install NombreDePaquete

La opción -f le indica a el gestor que de encontrar un conflicto instale la opción más acorde.

Comment: apt-get autoclean: todo OK  apt-get update: todo Ok  apt-get -f install mysql-server mysql-client, mismo error.

Comment: Pero el comando debe apuntar a mysql-communty-server así sudo apt-get -f install mysql-community-server.

Comment: Igualmente me aparece: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-community-server : Depends: mysql-common (>= 8.0.28-1debian11)
                          Depends: mysql-client (= 8.0.28-1debian11) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Que distribución de linux estas usando

Comment: Parrot Home Edition (Parrot OS 2.0 (LTS)). Encontre por otro lugar, buscando la opcion de instalar MariaDB en lugar de Mysql y lo instalo correctamente.

Comment: MariaDB tiene las mismas funcionalidades que MySQL y es la base de datos predeterminada en algunas diestros.

Comment: Perfecto! Ya lo tengo instalado y funcionando, gracias por comentar, me ayudo a seguir buscando y encontrar esta alternativa.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo instala MariaDB es lo mismo que instalar mysql, de hecho MariaDB es un Sistema de Gestión de Bases de Datos derivado de mysql.  Está desarrollado por Michael Widenius, uno de los fundadores de MySQL, la fundación MariaDB y la comunidad de desarrolladores de software libre.

Para instalarla ejecuta

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install mariadb-server`